# Open Cv face detection Attendance by locally stored images Android

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
Button facedetect;
GraphicOverlay graphicOverlay;
CameraView cameraView;
AlertDialog alertDialog;

Bitmap captureImage, saveImage;
Bitmap b1,b2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    facedetect = findViewById(R.id.detect_face_btn);
    graphicOverlay = findViewById(R.id.graphic_overlay);
    cameraView = findViewById(R.id.camera_view);


    facedetect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cameraView.start();
            cameraView.captureImage();
            graphicOverlay.clear();
        }
    });

    cameraView.addCameraKitListener(new CameraKitEventListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(CameraKitEvent event) {
            super.onEvent(event);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraKitError error) {
            super.onError(error);
        }

        @Override
        public void onImage(CameraKitImage image) {
            super.onImage(image);
            alertDialog.show();

            b1 = image.getBitmap();
            b1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b1, cameraView.getWidth(), cameraView.getHeight(), false);
            cameraView.stop();

            getImageFromLocal();`enter code here`
```

//                if (  compareImages(b1,b2)==true) {
//                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"True",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                }
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"False",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

```
            processFaceDetaection(b1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideo(CameraKitVideo video) {
            super.onVideo(video);
        }
    });

}


private void processFaceDetaection(Bitmap bitmap) {

    FirebaseVisionImage firebaseVisionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap);
    FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions firebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions = new FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder().build();

    // High-accuracy landmark detection and face classification
    FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions landmarkdetectionfacedetection =
            new FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                    .setPerformanceMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ACCURATE)
                    .setLandmarkMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_LANDMARKS)
                    .setClassificationMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
                    .build();

    // Real-time contour detection of multiple faces
    FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions contourdetectionfacedetection =
            new FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                    .setContourMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_CONTOURS)
                    .build();


    FirebaseVisionFaceDetector firebaseVisionFaceDetector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionFaceDetector(firebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions);
```

//        FirebaseVisionFaceDetector firebaseVisionFaceDetector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionFaceDetector(contourdetectionfacedetection);

```
    firebaseVisionFaceDetector.detectInImage(firebaseVisionImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionFace>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<FirebaseVisionFace> firebaseVisionFaces) {
            getFaceResult(firebaseVisionFaces);
            compareFaceFromLocal();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

private void compareFaceFromLocal() {

    if (compareImages(b1, b2) == true) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


private void getFaceResult(List<FirebaseVisionFace> firebaseVisionFaces) {

    int counter = 0;
    for (FirebaseVisionFace face : firebaseVisionFaces) {
        Rect rect = face.getBoundingBox();
        ReactOverlay reactOverlay = new ReactOverlay(graphicOverlay, rect);
        graphicOverlay.add(reactOverlay);

        counter = counter + 1;
    }

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No. of faces detected : " + counter, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    alertDialog.dismiss();
}


private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

static {
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
}

/**
 * Get the angle by which an image must be rotated given the device's current
 * orientation.
 */
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private int getRotationCompensation(String cameraId, Activity activity, Context context)
        throws CameraAccessException {
    // Get the device's current rotation relative to its "native" orientation.
    // Then, from the ORIENTATIONS table, look up the angle the image must be
    // rotated to compensate for the device's rotation.
    int deviceRotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int rotationCompensation = ORIENTATIONS.get(deviceRotation);
    // On most devices, the sensor orientation is 90 degrees, but for some
    // devices it is 270 degrees. For devices with a sensor orientation of
    // 270, rotate the image an additional 180 ((270 + 270) % 360) degrees.
    CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);
    int sensorOrientation = cameraManager
            .getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId)
            .get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
    rotationCompensation = (rotationCompensation + sensorOrientation + 270) % 360;
    // Return the corresponding FirebaseVisionImageMetadata rotation value.
    int result;
    switch (rotationCompensation) {
        case 0:
            result = FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_0;
            break;
        case 90:
            result = FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_90;
            break;
        case 180:
            result = FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_180;
            break;
        case 270:
            result = FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_270;
            break;
        default:
            result = FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_0;
            Log.e(TAG, "Bad rotation value: " + rotationCompensation);
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    cameraView.stop();
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    cameraView.start();
}


private void getImageFromLocal() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}




/*Compare two images.
 * @param bitmap1
 * @param bitmap2
 * @return true iff both images have the same dimensions and pixel values.*/

public static boolean compareImages(Bitmap bitmap1, Bitmap bitmap2) {
    if (bitmap1.getWidth() != bitmap2.getWidth() ||
            bitmap1.getHeight() != bitmap2.getHeight()) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < bitmap1.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < bitmap1.getWidth(); x++) {
            if (bitmap1.getPixel(x, y) != bitmap2.getPixel(x, y)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}


public static Uri imageURI;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == 0) {

            if (data != null) {
                try {
                    b2 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    } else {
        System.exit(0);
        Log.e("result", "BAD");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you explain the problem you are facing?

Comment: i can't be able to compare the two images as detected face is in different format and the local image is in different format as you see in the code.
Compare face always return false